# How to test the connection speed of a list of hosts?

Tags: networking, speed, ping

The background is that I want to find the fastest mirror for CTAN. And I don't want to ping their addresses one by one.

I searched this on google and found [`netselect`](http://apenwarr.ca/netselect/).
However, this seems not work on Windows, I tried cygwin, but the compilition failed, even without any error message.

So, is there a simple method to test their speed?

BTW, methods for Linux (expect `netselect`) is also welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with pinging the mirrors as a test see below -

```
while read line ; do ping -c 1 $line; done <mirrors.txt
```

then review the response times for each site.

**mirrors.txt**

```
www.yahoo.com
www.google.com
www.whitehouse.gov
etc.
```